# VNC: connection timeout

Tags: vnc, port-forwarding, vncserver, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I have [realvnc](http://www.realvnc.com/), the vnc server was giving some errors yesterday but i fixed them.

[image]

- I forwarded my ports

[image]

[image]

- My settings are correct

[image]

- Still i get connection timeout

[image]

I turned off my firewall, tried again, I got the same error, so the problem is not with my firewall. If i use SolusVm vnc viewer, it works. I'm trying to connect to my debian vps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should try to access it from inside your local network, if it works (probrably will) it means it is something with your router.

Did you created the VirtualServer correctly?

As far as i know the connections port and the java viewer port shall be different from each other. The java port is used to provide a java viewer client on browsers.

Try it